# I'm trying to use sfml in VSCode but I keep getting the error 'unidentified reference to winmain@16'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sfml

I'm new to using sfml and I wanted to test simple code in visual studio code,
Followed the tutorial on their website and and the basic code.

following the steps there was a command that i needed to run in the terminal for it to recognize the sfml libraries and after that i can run the code. Ran it and got the error, what do i do?

Comment: Do you have `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char**argv)` function in your code?

Comment: Just int main().

Comment: If you have more than 1 source file make sure you followed the instructions on how to modify your tasks.json to allow for budling more than 1 file. By default VSCode builds the active file into your executable and ignores all other files in your folder. The documentation tells you that here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you started a new *GUI* project, which expects `WinMain` to be your program’s entry point.

SFML works with a *console* project, which expects `main` to be your program entry point. If possible, retarget your solution to be a Console Application (IDK how to do this with VSCode, I don’t use it), or start a new Console Application project and copy your existing files into it.

PS. It might be possible there is a SFML Application project type as well... IDK if it exists by default or not... but if that exists use it instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if VSCode offers anything to create GUI projects like VS does. It would have to be an extension. But if they compile with MinGW, the error would mention WinMain for any program without `main` function.